# Parse yyyy/mm/dd to epoch timestamp using SimpleDateFormat in java

Tags: java, datetime, simpledateformat

I wrote a java utility function to convert yyyy/mm/dd as follows

```
public static long gettimestamp(String dateString) {
  SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/mm/dd");
  Date date;
  try {
  date = df.parse(dateString);
  } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
    return 0;
  }
  long epoch = date.getTime();
  return (epoch / 1000);
}
```

On passing 2014/06/12 - it gives 1389465360 (=Jan 11, 2014) which is wrong. Am I passing format in wrong way ?

Comment: Sorry, I was being impatient. Just realized "mm" is minutes and "MM" is month

Answer (score 4):

You should uppercase the `M`. Lowercase `m` stands for minutes, while uppercase stands for month. Here's the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate.parse("2014/06/12".replace("/" , "-"))
    .atStartOfDay(ZoneId.of("America/Montreal"))
    .toEpochSecond()
```

## Details

The [Answer by Cornelissen](http://Cornelissen) is correct, your formatting pattern is incorrect.

## Time zone

You fail to consider time zone. Your goal is getting a count of the seconds since the epoch of the start of 1970. That involves a time-of-day, when the day starts. The start of day varies around the globe by zone. A new day dawns earlier in Paris France than Montréal Québec.

## Avoid old date-time classes

Furthermore, you are using troublesome old legacy date-time classes now supplanted by the java.time classes.

## Use java.time

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuu/mm/dd" );
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( "2014/06/12" , f );
```

Alternatively, you could transform your input String to comply with standard ISO 8601 format by replacing the slash character with hyphen character. The java.time classes use ISO 8601 formats by default when parsing/generating strings.

Adjust that `LocalDate` into a specific time zone intended by the context of your date. We get a `ZonedDateTime` object.

Let java.time determine the start time of the day. Do not hard-code `00:00:00`. In some time zones anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time (DST) may result in a day starting at a time such as `01:00:00`.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );  // Or ZoneOffset.UTC if you meant UTC (GMT).
ZonedDateTime zdt = ld.atStartOfDay( z );
```

You may interrogate for the number of whole seconds since the epoch of `1970-01-01T00:00:00Z`.

```
long secondsSinceEpoch = zdt.toEpochSecond();
```

> 1402545600

### Avoid using count-from-epoch

By the way, I strongly recommend against tracking date-time values as a count-since-epoch. Hard to read, hard to debug, prone to errors, leads to ambiguity over different epochs used by different software systems (at least a couple dozen epochs have been used).

Case in point: Your expected value of `1389465360` makes no sense to me. Using `ZoneOffset.UTC` I get the start of that date as `1402531200`. Your expected value results in a time-of-day of 18:36 on January 11, 2014 when interpreted as a count of whole seconds since start of 1970 in UTC.

```
System.out.println ( Instant.ofEpochSecond ( 1_389_465_360L ).toString () );
```

> 2014-01-11T18:36:00Z

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the old troublesome date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `.Calendar`, & `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`.

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to java.time.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations.

Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further adapted to [Android](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system)) in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) (see [*How to use…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706)).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as `Interval`, `YearWeek`, `YearQuarter`, and more.