# Java - Check if a date is valid for a given dateformat

Tags: java, datetime, simpledateformat

I have the following code to check if a given date is valid

```
SimpleDateFormat fromformatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MMYY");
fromformatter.setLenient(false);

try {
    fromformatter.parse(dateString);
    valuesQuery.append("'" + dateString+ "',");
} catch (ParseException pe) {
    pe.printStackTrace();
    valuesQuery.append("'notDate" + dateString+ "',");
}
```

Now, when I get `dateString = "1803";` which is not a valid date, no exception is thrown. The date format that is being used here is `MMYY`.

What am i doing wrong?

Note that a regex will not help me as the date format will change.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse yyyy/mm/dd to epoch timestamp using SimpleDateFormat in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24217408/parse-yyyy-mm-dd-to-epoch-timestamp-using-simpledateformat-in-java)

Comment: `m` is for minutes, `M` is for month: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: I tried a couple of combinations of MMYY, MMyy. It doesnt catch the exception for 1803

Comment: For me, it works with `MMyy`: it throws `java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "1803"`

Answer (score 1):

"mm" is for minutes. Use "MMyy" instead. No exception is thrown as 18 is a valid value for minutes.

```
SimpleDateFormat fromformatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MMyy");
```

Please check: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html.

Comment: I tried a couple of combinations of MMYY, MMyy. It doesnt catch the exception for 1803

Answer (score 1):

## java.time

Use the modern java.time classes rather than the troublesome legacy date-time classes.

Specifically use the [`YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html) to represent such values. It's `parse` method will throw an exception for invalid input.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MMuu" ) ;
try {
    YearMonth ym = YearMonth.parse( "1803" , f ) ;
} catch ( DateTimeParseException e ) {
    … handle error.
}
```

TIP: If possible, use standard [ISO 8601](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats rather than that peculiar format. For year-month that would be YYYY-MM such as `2017-07`.